# How do link <form> action to an id tag in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to link the form action to an id tag, as I have created another page on the same html with `#pagetwo`.

```
<form method="post" action="#pagetwo">
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        //Form Fields

        <br><br>
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
        <label for="lname">Email:</label>
    </div>

    //Buttons
    <center>
    <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right">
    <input type="reset" data-inline="true" value="Reset" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right">           
</form>
```

Comment: You are using `<center>` which is deprecated and also not closing them. Crazy HTML!

Answer (score 1):

If you submit a form you are redirected to another page in every case. If you want to stay on the same page, you need to link it to the same page. You can do that by adding a `?` to the form action attribute. It will take the same URL without your current GET parameters as an action. You can add your hash tag afterwards.

```
<form method="post" action="?#pagetwo"></form>
```

Comment: And do not use ``<center />``. You can use the CSS style property ``text-align: center;`` for inline and inline-block elements.

Comment: it doesnt work , it always redirect me to the first page for some reason which is the problem i have been facing since just now

Comment: What do you mean by "page on the same html"? Do you have one ``.html`` file and two ``<div>``s where the second one has an attribute ``id="pagetwo"``? If yes, it should work like this.

Comment: its two <div> s where the second one has an attribute id="pagetwo"

Comment: but for some reason it keeps redirecting me back to pageone

Comment: <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo"> is the tag im currently using